# nginx with ip2location - invalid or empty results

Tags: nginx, module, ip2location

I have successfully installed ip2locations nginx module.
I have purchased the country library, however I get alot of responses that are either:

```
-
```

or

```
INVALID IPV4 ADDRESS
```

Is there something I can do to fix this issue? I have the dns through cloudflare but haven't activated the cdn feature so the traffic should go right through.

Comment: Do you have IPv6 traffics? Can you disable IPv6 first?

Comment: It is good if you can show us the IP address that generates "-" and "INVALID IPV4 ADDRESS". So we know how can we help you to troubleshoot.

Comment: FYI, you can get CloudFlare to add a geolocation header without any server side extensions: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168236-What-does-CloudFlare-IP-Geolocation-do-